# Node connection failed: check username / password on android monejuro monero wallet

Tags: monerujo, cakewallet

I just setup my own monero node and connected it to monejuro. I'm able to access my wallets, but one of the wallet keeps giving me the error:

```
Node connection failed: check username / password
```

The thing is that I don't have a username/password setup on this node. What could be wrong here? This wallet used to work, but now I keep getting this error.

Comment: Are you sure? Could you paste your config? Or are you maybe using one whereas you shouldn't?